Running KSP to replace Kapt in android project
I'm migrating from kapt to ksp , got few libraries that i need to migrate but upon building project , it threw few errors , I would be happy to get some help , Thank you

[versions]
agp = "8.4.1"
kspPlugin = "1.9.0-1.0.12"
androidxWorkRuntimeKtx = "2.10.0"
converterGson = "2.3.0"
hiltAndroid = "2.52"
hiltWork = "1.2.0"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.15.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
lifecycleViewmodelKtx = "2.8.7"
loggingInterceptor = "4.6.0"
material = "1.13.0-alpha07"
activity = "1.9.3"
constraintlayout = "2.2.0"
navigationFragmentVersion = "2.8.3"
retrofit = "2.7.1"
roomRuntime = "2.6.1"
workRuntimeKtx = "2.10.0"

[libraries]
androidx-activity-ktx = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-ktx", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-hilt-compiler = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltWork" }
androidx-hilt-work = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-work", version.ref = "hiltWork" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleViewmodelKtx" }
androidx-navigation-ui = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui", version.ref = "navigationFragmentVersion" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-work-runtime-ktx = { module = "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "workRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-work-runtime-ktx-v271 = { module = "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "androidxWorkRuntimeKtx" }
com-google-dagger-hilt-compiler2 = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
converter-gson = { module = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson", version.ref = "converterGson" }
google-hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-android-gradle-plugin = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-android-testing = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
logging-interceptor = { module = "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor", version.ref = "loggingInterceptor" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
navigation-fragment = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment", version.ref = "navigationFragmentVersion" }
retrofit = { module = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit", version.ref = "retrofit" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
jetbrains-kotlin-kotlin = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "kotlin" }
google-dagger-hilt-android = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref="kspPlugin" }




plugins {
   alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
   alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
   alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin)
   alias(libs.plugins.google.dagger.hilt.android)
   alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
}

android {
   namespace = "com.my.newsapp"
   compileSdk = 35

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId = "com.my.newsapp"
       minSdk = 24
       targetSdk = 35
       versionCode = 1
       versionName = "1.0"

       testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

   }

   buildFeatures {
       viewBinding = true
       dataBinding = true
       buildConfig = true
   }

   buildTypes {

       debug {
           buildConfigField(type = "String", name = "API_URL" , value = "\"https://newsapi.org/v2/\"")
           buildConfigField(type = "String", name = "API_KEY" , value = "\"--redacted--\"")
       }

       release {

           buildConfigField(type = "String", name = "API_URL" , value = "\"https://newsapi.org/v2/\"")
           buildConfigField(type = "String", name = "API_KEY" , value = "\"--redacted--\"")
           isMinifyEnabled = false
           proguardFiles(
               getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
               "proguard-rules.pro"
           )
       }
   }



   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }

   kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = "1.8"
   }

   kapt {
       correctErrorTypes  = true
   }

}

dependencies {
   ksp (libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)
   implementation (libs.androidx.hilt.work)
   implementation (libs.androidx.work.runtime.ktx.v271)
   implementation (libs.androidx.room.runtime)
   ksp (libs.androidx.room.compiler)
   implementation (libs.androidx.room.ktx)
   implementation (libs.navigation.fragment)
   implementation (libs.androidx.navigation.ui)
   implementation (libs.androidx.work.runtime.ktx)
   implementation (libs.androidx.activity.ktx)
   implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
   implementation (libs.retrofit)
   implementation (libs.converter.gson)
   implementation (libs.logging.interceptor)
   implementation (libs.hilt.android)
   ksp (libs.hilt.compiler)
   androidTestImplementation  (libs.hilt.android.testing)
   kaptAndroidTest (libs.google.hilt.compiler)
   testImplementation (libs.hilt.android.testing)
   kspTest (libs.com.google.dagger.hilt.compiler2)
   implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
   implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
   implementation(libs.material)
   implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
   implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
   testImplementation(libs.junit)
   androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
   androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}



// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath (libs.hilt.android.gradle.plugin)
    }
}
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.dagger.hilt.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp) apply false
}



java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'kotlin.KotlinVersion com.google.devtools.ksp.processing.SymbolProcessorEnvironment.getKspVersion()'
   at dagger.spi.internal.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspStarTypeArgumentType.<init>(KspStarTypeArgumentType.kt:43)
   at dagger.spi.internal.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspStarTypeArgumentType.<init>(KspStarTypeArgumentType.kt:28)
   at dagger.spi.internal.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspProcessingEnv.wrap(KspProcessingEnv.kt:281)
   at dagger.spi.internal.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspType$typeArguments$2.invoke(KspType.kt:198)
   at dagger.spi.internal.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspType$typeArguments$2.invoke(KspType.kt:194)
   at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
   at dagger.spi.internal.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspType.getTypeArguments(KspType.kt:194)



While irrelevant to your question I think you better remove your API key here.

probably related.

In your version catalog:

Remove the following libraries:
androidx-hilt-compiler
com-google-dagger-hilt-compiler2
google-hilt-compiler
hilt-android-gradle-plugin
hilt-compiler


Add the following library:
hilt-android-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }


Remove the kapt plugin jetbrains-kotlin-kotlin


In your top-level gradle file remove the following:

The entire buildscript block
The kapt plugin alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin) apply false

In your module-level gradle file:

Remove the kapt plugin alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin)

Remove the kapt block (the last element of the android block)

Remove the following from the dependencies block:
ksp (libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)
ksp (libs.hilt.compiler)
kaptAndroidTest (libs.google.hilt.compiler)
kspTest (libs.com.google.dagger.hilt.compiler2)


Add the following to the dependencies block:
ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
kspTest(libs.hilt.android.compiler)



That's it, after a Gradle sync you should be able to build the app again.

Thank you for your answer but still needed kapt for dataBinding .
